# Pyspark sqlContext.read.format and registerDataFrameAsTable

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I just started using spark sql and was wondering how do I transform a dataframe to a table using "registerDataFrameAsTable" after I have loaded it ?? I have all the headers and format correct, but I can't seem to transform it to a table.Is there another way that you are supposed to use ??

```
df = (sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                     .option("header", "true")
                     .load(dir))
```

This is my code above right now for loading the csv.

Comment: Have you tried `df.registerTempTable('table_name')`?

Answer (score 1):

```
'df.registerTempTable('table_name')
'sqlContext.sql("create table table_name as select * from table_name")'
```